# Transforming a closed polyline to a boundary of convex polygon

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Let $\ell$ be a closed polyline on a plane, i.e. 
$$\ell = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_iA_{i+1}$$
where $n\ge 3$ is an integer and $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are points on a plane such that for every $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ points $A_i, A_{i+1}, A_{i+2}$ are not collinear (we assume that $A_{n+1}=A_1$ and $A_{n+2}=A_2$).

Show that there exists a convex polygon $B_1B_2\ldots B_n$ such that for every $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ 
$$B_iB_{i+1}=A_iA_{i+1}$$
(again, $B_{n+1}=B_1$).

Comment: Can the sides of the polyline intersect?

Comment: They can intersect.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ sides $l_i=A_iA_{i+1}$ can form a convex polygon if and only if [every side is less than the sum of the other sides](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131625/determining-a-valid-convex-hexagon-given-the-length-of-six-sides). If we define $n$ vectors $\vec{l_i}=A_{i+1}-A_i$, then by definition $\sum_{i=0}^n\vec{l_i}=0$. It follows that for every $k$ between $1$ and $n$:
$$
l_k=|\vec{l_k}|=\left|\sum_{i\ne k}\vec{l_i}\right|\le
\sum_{i\ne k}|\vec{l_i}|=\sum_{i\ne k}{l_i}.
$$
Notice that inequality is strict if vectors $\vec{l_i}$ are not all on the same line.